# Excel VBA Custom Function Remove Words Appearing in One String From Another String

Tags: vba, function, excel, duplicates

I am trying to remove words appearing in one string from a different string using a custom function. For instance:

---

A1:

> the was why blue hat

A2:

> the stranger wanted to know why his blue hat was turning orange

The ideal outcome in this example would be:
A3:

> stranger wanted to know his turning orange

I need to have the cells in reference open to change so that they can be used in different situations.
The function will be used in a cell as:

> =WORDREMOVE(*"cell with words needing remove", "cell with list of words being removed"*)

I have a list of 20,000 rows and have managed to find a custom function that can remove duplicate words (below) and thought there may be a way to manipulate it to accomplish this task.

```
Function REMOVEDUPEWORDS(txt As String, Optional delim As String = " ") As String
Dim x
'Updateby20140924
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For Each x In Split(txt, delim)
        If Trim(x) <> "" And Not .exists(Trim(x)) Then .Add Trim(x), Nothing
    Next
    If .Count > 0 Then REMOVEDUPEWORDS = Join(.keys, delim)
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can guarantee that your words in both strings will be separated by spaces (no comma, ellipses, etc), you could just `Split()` both strings then `Filter()` out the words:

```
Function WORDREMOVE(ByVal strText As String, strRemove As String) As String

    Dim a, w
    a = Split(strText)             ' Start with all words in an array

    For Each w In Split(strRemove)
        a = Filter(a, w, False, vbTextCompare)  ' Remove every word found
    Next

    WORDREMOVE = Join(a, " ")      ' Recreate the string

End Function
```

Comment: this wouldn't be case sensitive would it?

Comment: Yes. But we can change that. Which one are you using?

Comment: The second one, I already have everything separated by a space.
Would I just put "LCase()" on the strText and strRemove?
Also, If I wanted to include more cells to the strRemove (list of words needing removal) would I just add "&" "&" and the additional cell

Comment: or is there a way to keep the word case?
&" "& does what I had hoped!
BTW - Thank You

Comment: @BrennanCasler - I removed the first option since the second one seems to meet your needs. I also edited the line `a = Filter(a, w, False)` to include a 4th parameter (`vbTextCompare`). That will do a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using Regular Expressions in VBA.  The version below is case insensitive and assumes all words are separated only by `space`.  If there is other punctuation, more examples would aid in crafting an appropriate solution:

```
Option Explicit
Function WordRemove(Str As String, RemoveWords As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .ignorecase = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(?:" & Join(Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(RemoveWords)), "|") & ")\s*"
    WordRemove = .Replace(Str, "")
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My example is certainly not the best code, but it should work

```
Function WORDREMOVE(FirstCell As String, SecondCell As String)

Dim FirstArgument As Variant, SecondArgument As Variant
Dim FirstArgumentCounter As Integer, SecondArgumentCounter As Integer
Dim Checker As Boolean

WORDREMOVE = ""

FirstArgument = Split(FirstCell, " ")
SecondArgument = Split(SecondCell, " ")

For SecondArgumentCounter = 0 To UBound(SecondArgument)
    Checker = False

    For FirstArgumentCounter = 0 To UBound(FirstArgument)

        If SecondArgument(SecondArgumentCounter) = FirstArgument(FirstArgumentCounter) Then
            Checker = True
        End If

    Next FirstArgumentCounter

    If Checker = False Then WORDREMOVE = WORDREMOVE & SecondArgument(SecondArgumentCounter) & " "

Next SecondArgumentCounter

    WORDREMOVE = Left(WORDREMOVE, Len(WORDREMOVE) - 1) 
End Function
```